# How to flatten nested array struct in Bigquery sql?

Tags: sql, arrays, struct, google-bigquery

The table looks as follows now:
[image]

My curent sql query looks like this -

```
select
 id, event.messageid as test_message, event[safe_offset(1)]
from dataset.table
where event.reason.reasoncode='damaged1';
```

Error:-

> Cannot access field reasoncode on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<reasonCode STRING,reasonDesc STRING>> at[9.29]

The query works fine without the where clause but the moment I add it, I am getting an error.Can anyone help?

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: can you pls also provide input data and expected outcome.

Comment: Hi @BihagKashikar, added output. The first table is the data available in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write a subquery on top of the array using `unnest()` which turns your array into a lateral (for this row only) temporary table:

```sql
select
 id, event.messageid as test_message, event[safe_offset(1)]
from 
  dataset.table
where 
  exists(select 1 from unnest(reason) where reasoncode='damaged1');
```

The `exists()` operator just checks if the subquery is returning anything or not

I'd recommend the [article on UNNEST()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator) and how to [work with arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/arrays#working_with_arrays).

Answer (score 1):

In order to query a field within the struct, you have to unnest the array first.

Try Below SQL.

```
SELECT id, event.messageid AS test_message, event[safe_offset(1)]
FROM dataset.table, UNNEST(event) AS event
WHERE event.reason.reasoncode='damaged1';
```